# Is there a way in Visual Studio 2012 to see an error log of the Update Service Reference operation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've had a lot of issues with updating my service reference to my WCF service.  I've had issues with third-party dll's not serializing correctly, and also issues with too many methods in the service.  I figure these out by trial and error or looking for similar posts.

It would be helpful if there was an error log to look at.  Does anyone know of a log or error log that visual studio writes out for this process?

Comment: you could look in the EventLog

Comment: I did that.  Nothing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio calls SVCUTIL.exe to do the majority of the work, IIRC. If you want to see a more verbose output of the process, use SVCUTIL yourself manually.

Comment: This is a workaround and not an answer to the original question

Answer (score 3):

You can start VS with log parameter:

```
Devenv.exe /log <path to log dir>
```

Comment: path is to log FILE, however it actually creates multiple files in that directory.  I'm not convinced about this answer though. didn't produce anything useful for me